# code:blocks startup error "pkg-config.exe"

Tags: windows, codeblocks, pkg-config

I am using Code:blocks 16.01 on windows 10. It used to work fine. however recently whenever I go on to open it, a Windows error or warning message shows up and says something like "pkg-config.exe has stopped working..."; then asks for "debug" or "close the programm"....>> I attach the picture of the event i just described. If I click on "close the program", code:blocks opens; other option fails to open it up. It is a bit annoying.

I thought that this was due to MS Visual Studio which I finally removed from my PC but the problem is still here.

I dont know if it is the right place to ask the question but I just need help, Please. 
See Picture description
[This is the error message that pops up before code:blocks opens up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gvmC.png)